# Why does map create new entries with operator[]

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm new to c++ and have a simple program as below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 std::map<std::string, double*> testMap;
 std::vector<std::string> v = {"A", "B", "C"};
 for(size_t i=0;i<v.size();++i)
 {
   std::string sym = v[i];
   double* d = testMap[sym];
   if(!d) continue;
   cout << "this";
 }
 for(std::map<std::string, double*>::iterator  itr=testMap.begin();itr!=testMap.end();++itr)
 {
    cout << itr->first << " " << itr->second << std::endl;
 }

 return 0;
}
```

and its O/P is

```
sh-4.3$ main                                                                                                                                                  
A 0                                                                                                                                                           
B 0                                                                                                                                                           
C 0
```

My question is why map is creating new elements with null double pointers

Comment: because this is what it does when the element doesn't exist: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at so it defaulted to a null pointer in this case, you declared an empty map but you then try to access elements at positions that didn't exist

Comment: What would you expect it to do?

Comment: I suspect you impression is it should behave something like the `find` member of  `std::map`, which returns an end-iterator on failure-to-locate. If that is the behavior you want, then that is the functionality you should be using; not `operator[]`.

Comment: Yes I assumed operator[] to behave as find(). Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at):

> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to
>   key, performing an insertion if such key does not already exist.
>
> If an insertion is performed, the mapped value is value-initialized
>   (default-constructed for class types, zero-initialized otherwise) and
>   a reference to it is returned.

For `double*`, the zero-initialized value is a null pointer.

You could modify the value inserted by `std::map::operator[]`:

```
testMap[sym] = ...something...;
```

or specify the key and value by `std::map::insert`:

```
testMap.insert({sym, ...something...});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write `testMap[sym]` a check is done whether `sym` exists in map, and if it does then reference to it is returned. If it does not then new entry value initialized is inserted into map with key `sym`, in your case it is a null pointer.

So if you dont want to have null vaules, then check if key exists with [std::map::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find), and compare to `std::map::end()`, instead of using `std::map::operator[]`

> My question is why map is creating new elements with null double pointers

this is how standard defines behaviour of [std::map::operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

n4140 23.4.4.3 map.access

> T& operator[](const key_type& x);
>
> Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts
>   value_type(x, T()) into the map.

and:

> T& operator[](key_type&& x);
>
> Effects: If there is no key equivalent to x in the map, inserts value_type(std::move(x), T()) into
>   the map.

Answer (score 0):

That is the way maps works.
The map must be check if the key is all raedy containt.
Use find(key) for that. In your excample testMap[sym]; creates a new entry.

```
std::map<std::string,double*>::iterator it;
it = testMap.find("A");
if ( it == testMap.end() )
{ // create a new entry
   testMap["A"] = new double(1.0);
}
```

Match fun
Hilko